# Calling JSP Custom Tags tld through Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, custom-tags

So I am currently trying to implement `AJAX` functionality to my webapp.
I currently have all the Tag Library, Tag Handlers, set up properly, so that if I call the Tags when the page is fully refreshing. All these custom tags work.
However, I have actually never implemented `ajax` in my life and is currently stuck on how to proceed to call these tags dynamically based on the changes in the webpage.
E.X:

Custom Tag library under -->`/WEB-INF/tld`

Tag Handlers --> `classes/ClassHandlers/Tag1...TagXXX`

With the above calling the following tag in the JSP file works perfectly:

```
<tagLib:tagName Attribute1="" Attribute2="">
```

However, how can I get this to be dynamically inserted by Ajax?

Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: Okay, so from pawel's answer, it seems like Ajax is not an option to dynamically call in new jsp tags without refreshing the entire page? Or is there another route I can take to handle this type of problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would said that it is impossible. AJAX and JSP are two incompatible technologies. JSP tags can be used only on **server side** (during generating HTML) while AJAX is a **client side** technology (it runs in user browser). You can read more about client-server model [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

Comment: Hi, from what I have read and maybe misunderstood. I though that AJAX was suppose to allow the client to retrieve information from the server asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, AJAX allows us to ask server asynchronously. This means that your AJAX can ask for JSP file and inside it call JSP tag, but I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: Perfect, so if I set a jsp that only contains <tagLib:tagName Attribute1="" Attribute2=""> my page would be able to fetch that?
Also, if that is the case is there any way to pass in dynamic attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You can pass dynamic attributes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762588/how-do-i-make-dynamic-attributes-work-in-jsp-tag-files) using request parameters. Just curious, why do you want to do it? What is so special in that tag? Why can't you implement it in Java Script?